# Map Reduce Program throwing exception IOException "Type mismatch in key from map"

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi Please find my Code Below, Which is throwing exception.

```
package HadoopMapReduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class HospitalsMapReduce {

    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private Text val = new Text();

        public void map(Text key, Text value, Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("This is Value " + value);

            String rec[] = value.toString().split(",");
            String disease=rec[0];
            String name = rec[1];
            String loc = rec[2];
            int budget = Integer.parseInt(rec[3]);
            int rating = Integer.parseInt(rec[4]);
            String val1=1+","+name+","+budget+","+rating;



            if (loc.equalsIgnoreCase("Pune")) {
                word.set(disease);
                val.set(val1);
                context.write(word, val);
            }

        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text result = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                Reducer.Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            int sum = 0;
            int budget=0;
            float avgBudget=0;
            while(values.hasNext())
             {
                  String value[]=values.next().toString().split(",");
                  sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
                  budget=budget+ Integer.parseInt(value[2]);                 
             }

            avgBudget=budget/sum;

            result.set(sum+" "+avgBudget);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000");
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path output = new Path("/test/output2/");
        if (hdfs.exists(output)) {
            hdfs.delete(output, true);
        }
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Hospital count");
        job.setJarByClass(HospitalCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class,Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/test/hospital"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Here is My Error Log :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/NetBeansProjects/BDGRUSDML/Libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/NetBeansProjects/BDGRUSDML/Libs/slf4j-nop-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2016-05-29 11:50:41,302 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-05-29 11:50:41,965 INFO  Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1173)) - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2016-05-29 11:50:41,965 INFO  jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2016-05-29 11:50:42,024 WARN  mapreduce.JobResourceUploader (JobResourceUploader.java:uploadFiles(64)) - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2016-05-29 11:50:42,046 WARN  mapreduce.JobResourceUploader (JobResourceUploader.java:uploadFiles(171)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2016-05-29 11:50:42,093 INFO  input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(283)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2016-05-29 11:50:42,148 INFO  mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(198)) - number of splits:1
2016-05-29 11:50:42,255 INFO  mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:printTokens(287)) - Submitting tokens for job: job_local527592655_0001
2016-05-29 11:50:42,439 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:submit(1294)) - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2016-05-29 11:50:42,440 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1339)) - Running job: job_local527592655_0001
2016-05-29 11:50:42,441 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(471)) - OutputCommitter set in config null
2016-05-29 11:50:42,450 INFO  output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:<init>(100)) - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2016-05-29 11:50:42,455 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:createOutputCommitter(489)) - OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2016-05-29 11:50:42,537 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(448)) - Waiting for map tasks
2016-05-29 11:50:42,538 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(224)) - Starting task: attempt_local527592655_0001_m_000000_0
2016-05-29 11:50:42,565 INFO  output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:<init>(100)) - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2016-05-29 11:50:42,579 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(612)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2016-05-29 11:50:42,584 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:runNewMapper(756)) - Processing split: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/test/hospital/hospitals.txt:0+624
2016-05-29 11:50:42,671 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:setEquator(1205)) - (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2016-05-29 11:50:42,672 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(998)) - mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2016-05-29 11:50:42,672 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(999)) - soft limit at 83886080
2016-05-29 11:50:42,672 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(1000)) - bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2016-05-29 11:50:42,672 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:init(1001)) - kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2016-05-29 11:50:42,675 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:createSortingCollector(403)) - Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2016-05-29 11:50:42,733 INFO  mapred.MapTask (MapTask.java:flush(1460)) - Starting flush of map output
2016-05-29 11:50:42,747 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(456)) - map task executor complete.
2016-05-29 11:50:42,760 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(560)) - job_local527592655_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-29 11:50:43,444 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1360)) - Job job_local527592655_0001 running in uber mode : false
2016-05-29 11:50:43,446 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1367)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2016-05-29 11:50:43,449 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1380)) - Job job_local527592655_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2016-05-29 11:50:43,465 INFO  mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1385)) - Counters: 0
```

---

Edit :

---

After Modifying below code I am able to execute my code now. 
From Reducer.Context to Context

```
public void map(Text key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Please find below updated code :

```
package HadoopMapReduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class HospitalsMapReduce {

    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private Text val = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("This is Value " + value);

            String rec[] = value.toString().split(",");
            String disease=rec[0];
            String name = rec[1];
            String loc = rec[2];
            int budget = Integer.parseInt(rec[3]);
            int rating = Integer.parseInt(rec[4]);
            String val1=1+","+name+","+budget+","+rating;



            if (loc.equalsIgnoreCase("Pune")) {
                word.set(disease);
                val.set(val1);
                context.write(word, val);
            }

        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Iterator<Text>, Text, Text> {

        private Text result = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            int sum = 0;
            int budget=0;
            float avgBudget=0;

             System.out.println("This is Reducer Jobs");

            while(values.hasNext())
             {
                  String value[]=values.next().toString().split(",");
                   System.out.println("This is Value " + value);
                  sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
                  budget=budget+ Integer.parseInt(value[2]);                 
             }

            avgBudget=budget/sum;

            result.set(sum+" "+avgBudget);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000");
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path output = new Path("/test/output2/");
        if (hdfs.exists(output)) {
            hdfs.delete(output, true);
        }
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Hospital_count");
        job.setJarByClass(HospitalsMapReduce.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        //job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/test/hospital/"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

But Now my problem is, Reducer function is not getting executed. My output only shows output of map function.

Comment: why do you declare multipleoutputs, if you are not using that? Also, you should cast `budget` or `sum` to float or double before making the division for `avgBudget`. Do you see "This is Reducer Jobs" and "This is value ..." in the out logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hadoop Iterable inplace of Java Iterator.

Change your reducer definition and code as follows.

```
public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
private Text result = new Text();
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("This is Red Value ");
    int sum = 0;
    int budget = 0;
    float avgBudget = 0;
    System.out.println("This is Reducer Jobs");
    for (Text val : values) {
        String value[] = val.toString().split(",");
        System.out.println("This is Reduce Value " + value);
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
        budget = budget + Integer.parseInt(value[2]);
    }
    avgBudget = budget / sum;
    result.set(sum + " " + avgBudget);
    context.write(key, result);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working perfectly now after few more modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I will summarize your issue as

> My keys and values are all strings (`Text`) but the Map/Reduce
>   framework believes I am providing numbers (`LongWritable`)

Well I would agree that the source code would likely make that impossible since all of the mapper/reducer keys and values are `Text`.

So you might want to look into the *packaging* of your app jar file - to see if you were getting the correct versions being shipped to the hadoop cluster.  Otherwise it just seems your code could not end up with the given exceptions.

Comment: please review my latest updated code. Now I my reducer function is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks your combiner is causing the issue. You have used your reducer functions as your combiner. However, the output format of the map function and combiner function is not same which should not happen. The combiner is called on the output of map functions and is an input to further combiner operations or to reduce operations. Reducer expects the same format of Key-Value pairs from the data that reaches it, whether it comes out after combiner processing or not.

Also, from the code written above, i see that finding averages in combiner function is not the right thing to do. The averages will never come out to be correct.

For of all, remove the combiner operation as its only for boosting performance. Introduce it once you know your code works well functionally.

Comment: Hi @preeti , This is not my actual logic. I was just trying to do something using mapreduce.

Comment: Change this line ::

 public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Iterator<Text>, Text, Text>
 to 

Change this line :: public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text,Text, Text, Text>

Answer (score 0):

your reducer definition should look like,

```
public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     //your logic
    }

}
```